# What attribute should I add in my HTML to avoid different inputs from users

Tags: html, laravel-5

This is my HTML for effective date:

```
<input class="form-control input-md datepicker" name="effective_date" 
type="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
```

This is a screenshot of my DB [image]

You would notice there are two different formats of dates that got through. How can avoid this in my html, and if you can also help me how to correct those already submitted.

Comment: Validate against a list of acceptable formats (or just 1) using JS if you really care how they're inputting it (better yet, use a datepicker for imrpoved UX). Then validate it again on the server. Then normalize it to an ISO 8601 date `yyyy-mm-dd` before putting it in your database. Storing dates as strings doesn't make a lot of sense, especially since you'll lose out on SQL's capabilities with dates.

Comment: type="date" is not supported in Firefox, or Internet Explorer 11 and earlier versions. So, you should use server side validation to avoid multiple date formats in database.

Comment: hi @PranitJha, how do I do a server side validation

Comment: also, each browser will interpret that 'type="date"' respecting the user location format.

Comment: if you want to turn it into a single format only you should use masks or date pickers. For example: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ . Then you must validate the expected format on server side.

Comment: Hi @KikoGarcia how do I do a server side validation? any references?

Comment: which language you're using to store that on database? PHP? Python?

Comment: Your first mistake is storing your date as a string in the database, it should be stored as a DateTime type, most, if not all, SQL databases have this.

Comment: @RodneyZanoria sorry, just noticed you mentioned "laravel 5.2". Whatever, look this: http://laravelbook.com/laravel-input-validation/